# mining transaction in private blockchain

Tags: transactions, private-blockchain, mining, gas-estimate

I am new to the blockchain issue, and I have read about it, but I had these questions.

When I actually implement a private Blockchain  on every transaction it costs a certain gas. Who pays for this gas ???

Likewise, in Private Blockchain, as I understood, we can determine who will pay miners who will pay miners for verification of the correctness of the transactions ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's a regular Proof-of-Work blockchain then the miners' rewards are minted, so they appear out of thin air. Here's some more info about mining: https://cointelegraph.com/ethereum-for-beginners/how-to-mine-ethereum-guide-for-beginners

As for the gas cost, the sender of the transaction always pays for the gas. But as it's your own blockchain this is quite irrelevant as you can circumvent this "problem" by for example setting `gas price` to `0` in the transaction. Or, as it's your blockchain you will get all the mining rewards so you can just use those, for example.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I understood the transactions, but the miners' rewards didn't get much. Can you explain that more ??

Comment: Added a link to a mining article